# How to get URL and Title from link dragged from browser

Tags: c#

I'd like my application to accept a link dragged and dropped from a browser and then display the URL and Title of the link.

Edit: I should have been more clear, I mean the link in the address bar of a browser.

```
private void test_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
     e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

private void test_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
     string text = string.Empty;
     if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.UnicodeText))
     {
          text = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText).ToString();
          Console.WriteLine("text: {0}", text);
     }
}
```

With this code I can get the URL, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask but not the page title like "Ask a question".

There are many DataFormats available like DragContext, DragImageBits, text/x-moz-url, FileGroupDescriptorW, FileContents, UniformResourceLocatorW, UniformResourceLocator, System.String, UnicodeText, and Text.

Which one is the best one to use, and how do I extract the information?

Comment: you want the title of the page the link was dragged from, or the title of the page the link is pointing to? I'll guess the latter, from what you've said? In either case, I don't think a simple hyperlink tag will contain that information. It's just a URL. If you're lucky, the _link itself_ might have a title or other descriptive text, but that doesn't tell you anything about the page it links to. To get that, you'd have to make a HTTP request to the URL and then parse the resulting HTML response (assuming the URL actually returns a HTML page, and not something else).

Comment: Edit: I should have been more clear, I mean the link in the address bar of a browser. It seems the information is available in the text/x-moz-url format, I just don't know how to retrieve it.

Comment: if "text/x-moz-url" is one of the formats specified (by running `e.Data.GetFormats()` I assume?), then I'd expect you get the data via `e.Data.GetData("text/x-moz-url")`. You might need `.ToString()` on the end as well. You can check all the other specified formats in the same way to see what's inside them, if you need to. N.B. I haven't used this feature at all but that's my understanding just from reading the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.idataobject?view=netframework-4.8). If it works let me know and I'll write it up as a proper answer :-)

Comment: I tried e.Data.GetData("text/x-moz-url").ToString() and I get "System.IO.MemoryStream". I then used var data = e.Data.GetData("text/x-moz-url"); and set a breakpoint to examine data. It contains a buffer with information... any suggestions on how I could retrieve that buffer?

Comment: Thanks @ADyson for your assistance. I'm answering my question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page title and URL are available in the "text/x-moz-url" data format. This works for the current versions of the Chrome and Firefox browsers.

```
if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("text/x-moz-url"))    //Chrome, Firefox
 {
      MemoryStream data = (MemoryStream)e.Data.GetData("text/x-moz-url");
      string dataStr = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data.ToArray());
      string[] parts = dataStr.Split(((char)10));
      for (int i = 0; i < parts.Count(); i++ )
      {
          listBox1.Items.Add(parts[i]);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The link does not contain the title. You will have to do a HTTP request and parse the HTML to get the title:

```
<title>Ask a Question - Stack Overflow</title>
```